# empty data in Laravel query

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

my response always empty !

if I run only one (where) separated  in the Query I get data

but

if I run all three ( where ) Its  empty !

```
 $find= consultationsBridge::whereBetween(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'), array($searchFrom, 
          $searchTo))
        ->where('branch',$branch)
        ->where('type',$type)
        ->paginate(50);

    return  $find;
```

my output

```
{
  "current_page": 1,
  "data": [
    
  ],
  "first_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/search?page=1",
  "from": null,
  "last_page": 1,
  "last_page_url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/search?page=1",
  "next_page_url": null,
  "path": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/search",
  "per_page": 50,
  "prev_page_url": null,
  "to": null,
  "total": 0
}
```

Comment: Can you please remove the paginate function for now, and try the function toSql instead of that for once? You'll get the entire query that is being generated by Laravel. Moreover, to find the exact value that is being used by Laravel you can use the function "getBindings". Combining these 2 results please verify the output again.

Comment: I think your whereBetween is wrong, why are you using DB::raw('DATE(created_at)') as first param, maybe you need use simply 'created_at' ?

Comment: thanks guys the next answer is right !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller code to something like this

```
$from = date($searchFrom);
$to = date($searchTo);
$find = consultationsBridge::whereBetween('created_at', [$from,$to])
            ->where([['branch',$branch],['type',$type]])
            ->paginate(50);
return  $find;
```

And if there's an OR condition between branch and type then change your code like this

```
$from = date($searchFrom);
$to = date($searchTo);
$find = consultationsBridge::whereBetween('created_at', [$from,$to])
            ->where('branch',$branch)
            ->orWhere('type',$type)
            ->paginate(50);
return  $find;
```

Comment: @AndrewNady My pleasure !